# PostgreSQL: Find row with JSON object attribute in array

Tags: postgresql, json, array

I have a postgres database which is set up like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE arr_test (
  id serial primary key,
  data jsonb
);

INSERT INTO arr_test (data) VALUES 
  ('{"test_row": 1, "my_arr": [{"serial":"AAA", "content":"123"}, {"serial":"BBB", "content":"345"}]}'),
  ('{"test_row": 2, "my_arr": [{"serial":"CCC", "content":"456"}, {"serial":"DDD", "content":"567"}]}'),
  ('{"test_row": 3, "my_arr": [{"serial":"AAA", "content":"678"}, {"serial":"EEE", "content":"789"}]}');
```

I am trying to write a query where the data contains a list which has an object which contains a value. In this case it is the serial-field of the objects in the array that I want to query for.
For example, if I query for serial 'AAA' I want test row 1 and 3 to be returned, and if I query for serial 'EEE' I want only test row 3.

I have experimented with `jsonb_array_elements` and `jsonb_to_recordset` but am getting nowhere and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to unnest the array elements and combine that with an EXISTS condition

```
select t.*
from arr_test t
where exists (select *
              from jsonb_array_elements(t.data -> 'my_arr') as x(o)
              where x.o ->> 'serial' = 'AAA');
```

Alternatively you can write that with a contains operator `@>`:

```
select t.*
from arr_test t
where exists (select *
              from jsonb_array_elements(t.data -> 'my_arr') as x(o)
              where x.o @> '{"serial": "AAA"}');
```

[Try it on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=be7e6e50567786ec476ff26437393448)

Answer (score 1):

This can also work

```
select
t.id,
jsonb_path_query(data, '$ ? (@.my_arr[*].serial == "AAA")')
from arr_test t
```

From official docs:
[JSON Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)

```
jsonb_path_query ( target jsonb, path jsonpath [, vars jsonb [, silent boolean ]] ) → setof jsonb
```

Returns all JSON items returned by the JSON path for the specified JSON value. The optional vars and silent arguments act the same as for jsonb_path_exists.

```
select * from jsonb_path_query('{"a":[1,2,3,4,5]}', $.a[*] ? (@ >= $min && @ <= $max)', 

'{"min":2, "max":4}') →

 jsonb_path_query
------------------
 2
 3
 4
```

Regarding performance comparison to the previous answer, I do not know. Index awareness in jsonb functions was not on the top but it is getting better with every Postgres release.